# Get json object that has latest timestamp using jq

Tags: json, jq

I have a below json file but I'm struggling to only display the `description` with the latest `createdDate`.

I tried with

```
>
<
todateiso8601?
now
```

and a few more but I can't get this to work.

Would anyone be able to help?

JSON:

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "createdDate": 1543585940, 
            "id": "awefef", 
            "description": "this is description 1"
        }, 
        {
            "createdDate": 1555324487, 
            "id": "hjkvhuk", 
            "description": "this is description 2"
        }, 
        {
            "createdDate": 1547034297, 
            "id": "xdfxdfv", 
            "description": "this is description 3"
        }
]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply sort by .createdDate and (assuming you only want one value even if there is more than one with the greatest .createdDate value), select the last one:

```
.items
| sort_by(.createdDate)[-1].description
```

#### Ties

If you want all the descriptions in the case of ties:

```
.items
| sort_by(.createdDate)
| (.[-1].createdDate) as $max
| .[]
| select($max == .createdDate)
| .description
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: use peaks answer it is superior

Here is a simple script that does this in 2 commands. Probably can be done in 1 but alas my nooblet skills were not enough

You can pipe to `max` with an array of numbers in JQ and it will return the largest value in the input array.

Then we use `select` to grab the object containing the max value and output the description.

We will also use `arg` which allows us to reference a local environment variable, and we need to cast it to a number or JQ thinks it's a string.

`maxDate=$(cat tmp.json | jq '[.items[].createdDate] | max')`

`cat tmp.json | jq --arg maxDate "$maxDate" '.[][] | select(.createdDate == ($maxDate | tonumber)).description'`

Output:

```
"this is description 2"
```

In the future, please post your desired output as well as your question so responders can be confident they are solving the problem to your liking

Comment: You can use `--argjson maxDate` to save the call to `tonumber`.